# Libgdx - Use void as an agrument in a function

Tags: java, android, libgdx, arguments, void

i'm trying to make a void with a Void as an argument in libgdx,
how do i make it work?

this is what i have:

```
public class ReleaseDetector{

        boolean Touched = false;

        //
        // --- Simple void for touch release detection, when looped. ---
        // --- and the argument void, or how i imagine it..
        //
        public void ReleaseListener(void MyArgumentVoid)//<---The argument void
        {
            if (Gdx.input.isTouched()){

                Touched = true;
            }
            if (!Gdx.input.isTouched() && Touched){
            MyArgumentVoid();<----------// Call for a void from the Argument.
            Touched = false;
            }
        }
}
```

Usage in MyGdxGame class, or how i imagine it:

```
public class MyGdxGame extends ApplicationAdapter {

int Counter = 0;
ReleaseDetector RD = new ReleaseDetector();

    public void AddCounter(){// just a simple void.
        Counter++;
    }

    @Override
    public void render() { // Render Loop void.
    RD.ReleaseListener(AddCounter);// how i imagine it's usage.
    }
}
```

now, how am i making it real? i hope there is a simple way..

Comment: You don't want a void as a parameter, you want a function with no return nor parameters.

Comment: You have learn to follow java naming conventions first, you are writing code with a mind of C or something like that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you need a **callback method** which takes no argument and returns `void`.

```
public class ReleaseDetector {

    boolean touched = false;

    public void releaseListener(MyGdxGame game) { // Argument
        if (Gdx.input.isTouched()) {
            touched = true;
        }
        if (!Gdx.input.isTouched() && touched){
            game.addCounter();                    // Callback
            touched = false;
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
public class MyGdxGame extends ApplicationAdapter {

    int counter = 0;
    ReleaseDetector detector = new ReleaseDetector();

    public void addCounter() {
        counter++;
    }

    @Override
    public void render() { // Render Loop.
        detector.releaseListener(this);
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.